# How do you derive (9.10) from the Feynman lectures Vol. III?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, two-level-system

The [Feynman lectures volume 3 chapter 9](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_09.html) analyzes the ammonia molecule. It assumes there are only two base states. The amplitude, $C_1$, to be in the first state, $\lvert1\rangle$, in which the nitrogen atom is above the plane of the three hydrogen atoms is given by,

$$C_1=\frac{a}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}+\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)t}.\tag{9.2}$$

and the amplitude, $C_2$, for the nitrogen atom to be in the second base state, $\lvert2\rangle$, where the nitrogen atom is below this plane is,

$$C_2=\frac{a}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}-\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)t}.\tag{9.3}$$

There are two stationary states. The first one is $\lvert\psi_I\rangle$ and corresponds to when $a=0$ in $(9.2)$ and $(9.3)$. The other one is $\lvert\psi_{II}\rangle$ and corresponds to when $b=0$ in $(9.2)$ and $(9.3)$. The amplitude to be in the new base states $C_I$ and $C_{II}$ are given as,

$$C_I=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[C_1-C_2], \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C_{II}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[C_1+C_2].\tag{9.13}$$

Equation $(9.10)$ for the state $\lvert\psi_I\rangle$, also says these amplitudes should be,

$$C_I=e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)t}, \ \ \ \ C_{II}=0.\tag{9.10}$$

When I try to calculate $C_{II}$ for state $\lvert\psi_I\rangle$ for when $a=0$,  I get,

$C_{II}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[C_1+C_2]=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}-\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}]=0$

which is the same $C_{II}$ as given in $(9.10)$, but when I try to calculate $C_{I}$ I get,

$C_I=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[C_1-C_2]=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}+\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}]=\frac{b}{\sqrt2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)t}$

This is exactly the same as $C_{I}$ in $(9.10)$ except for the factor $\frac{b}{\sqrt2}$. Are you able to just assume that $b=\sqrt2$ to eliminate this factor and make $C_I$ equal to what is shown in $(9.10)$, or is this incorrect?

Comment: If you give more background information people would not have the consult the Feynman Lecture before they can answer your question.

Comment: I didn't have to consult the Feynman Lectures to understand this question and I see nothing wrong with consulting it, so it seems to me flippiefanus's comment is merely flippant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant $b$ can be solved as follows. Suppose that at $t=0$ we know the molecule is in state $\lvert{I}\rangle$, then $C_{I}(0)=1$. Now knowing that $a=0$

$C_I(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[C_1(0)-C_2(0)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}[\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)(0)}+\frac{b}{2}e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)(0)}]=\frac{b}{\sqrt2}=1$

Therefore,

$b={\sqrt2}$